# How to show large number of user locations on Map using MKMapkit in iPhone

Tags: ios, web-services, mapkit, mkannotation, mkcoordinateregion

We are creating a map based iPhone application using MKMapkit. In which we are  getting the current location and the zoom out and zoo in co-ordinates of visible region. We need to show n number (say more than 1000) of user locations on the map, and this co-ordinates are getting from a web service. 
At the first launch, it will pass the current location and co-ordinates of visible region and will get the list of other user's co-ordinates. We know how to display locations of user's. But the issue is, how should we call the service in zoom-in and zoom-out events of the map?
Should we load all the co-ordinates in a single call and display corresponding user locations? Or should we call the service by passing the co-ordinates of visible region, while we are zooming in or out using the delegate methods?
Which one is the proper way to implement this? 
Please reply.

Comment: I think all locations should be load at a time when we opening mapview but have to show visible region at first of main user's location.

Comment: ok, so is it possible to load all the values to the map even the values in the visible region? or is it load automatically when zoom-in or out?

Comment: Yeah,if u take the longitude,latitude values of all from webservice  in an array and by running a loop you can throw multiple pins using that values.